# Running Total of a Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where each `Group` has many records. In these records I have a `Running Total` that returns `True` if the fields text matches a certain criteria using the `Max` type - so one or more matches = `True`. This is located at the bottom of each group. I now need to count how many groups have a `True` - so it's like a `Running Total` of a `Running Total` - which is not allowed so how do I wire this up? Other ideas for getting this count would be entertained. Thanks for your help...

Layout:

```
Record(Group Header)
              True(function)
              True(function)
              False(function)    
                       {1}(Group Footer)
Record(Group Header)
              False(function)
              False(function)   
                       {0}(Group Footer)

                     {total}(Page Footer)
```

Comment: Create a formula that returns a value if the Running Total returns "true". Then do a running total of that formula's value.

Comment: Running total cannot refer to a print time function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is one way of doing this. It may seem counterintuitive, but it works. Create a formula "max". The content of that formula is:

```
if {criteria} = true then 1
else 0
```

Put that formula in your Detail Section. It will give you a 1 if your criteria equals true and a 0 if the criteria is false. Now right-click on the @max formula in the detail section and click Insert -> Summary. Create a sum and put it in the Group Footer. Now create a second formula "SumMax". The content of that formula is:

```
if {@max} > 0 then 1
else 0
```

Put that formula also in your Group Footer. Now right-click on "@SumMax" and do Insert -> Summary and choose Sum. Put that in the Report Footer. Suppress @max and/or @SumMax as you please.
The way it works is that it counts all the true's of your criteria in a group (@max). If the result is greater than 0, @SumMax will count 1. Then you summarize the count of @SumMax, which gives you the total.

Comment: @max only evaluates the last field in the details section not all the fields for a true value...

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Put @max in the detail section, then insert a summary of "@sum" in the Group Footer. Put "@SumMax" in the Group Footer and proceed as stated in my answer. I got mixed up.

Comment: Same results, I can see 0's and 1's but the @sumMax only shows the last field value???

Comment: No, SumMax gives you a 1 if max is > 0. That is done so for each group that has a true value you get a 1, so when you do the final summary in the report footer you get an accurate count of how many groups have a true value.

Comment: Well, I have done what you said and it does not work. Each field is evaluated with the @max function correctly, even when the functions return correctly the running totals will not evaluate them - they don't show as a field to eval on. This is getting uber frustrating!

Comment: I edited my original answer to make up for my error. Please re-read it again to make sure we are on the same page. "@sum" evaluates the criteria, which seems to be working. The summary of "@sum" gives you the total of "true" evaluations. If that summary is greater than 0, then our "@SumMax" formula, which is in the Group Footer, just like the summary of "@sum", should give us a 1, otherwise it gives a 0. And the summary of "@SumMax" in the Report Footer gives us the total count . There are no {RTotal} (running totals) in this report now, everything is done "manually".

Comment: Any chance you can provide a screenshot of your report design with al the formulas in place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42365/discussion-between-dona-and-campagnolo-1)

Comment: Have you made any progress? I'm still dumbfounded that you can't insert a summary of @SumMax from the Group Footer to the Report Footer.

Comment: No, it has me baffled as well. I don't get stumped very easily. Maybe it's a version thing. I am using `v10` - and have no option to upgrade right now.